# What is the correct Fontconfig syntax for substituting a given uninstalled font with an installed font?

Tags: fonts

[The Fontconfig documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) is fairly opaque. I want applications looking up the 'Helvetica' family to instead receive the 'Helvetica LT Std' family and display that font, browsers in particular. The latest XML file I wrote to ~/.fontconfig/fonts.conf was

```
<fontconfig>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family" target="default" compare="eq">
            <string>Helvetica</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign">
            <string>Helvetica LT Std</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

</fontconfig>
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be a correct way to express this substitution?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me to replace Arial with Ubuntu

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?>-->
<!--DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">-->
<!-- ~/.fonts.conf for per-user font configuration -->
<fontconfig>
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>Arial</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
        <string>Ubuntu</string>
        <string>Arial</string>
    </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

I found fc-match to be super helpful.

Also, I am on Precise so I use ~/.fonts.conf. In Quntal I understand you should use
~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly the same substitution I'm using!  This is my configuration, but it only works when the specified font is not available.  If the specified font was accessible by fontconfig, named *Helvetica*, the alias would not apply.  However this has been working correctly on all my Ubuntu installations, so I recommend it before using the **match** tag.

```
<fontconfig>

<!-- Excerpt -->

    <alias>
        <family>Helvetica</family>
        <accept>
            <family>Helvetica LT Std</family>
        </accept>
    </alias>

<!-- Excerpt -->

</fontconfig>
```